# custom mail in magento

Tags: magento

I am sending a custom email to admin and it works properly but when I refresh the page following error occurred:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function send() on a non-object app/design/frontend/default/default/template/custom/custom.phtml on line 457   my code is 


$emailadminTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('custom_email_template_to_admin_customproduct');
$emailadminTemplate->setSenderName($salesData['name']);
$emailadminTemplate = array();
$emailadminTemplate['name'] = $salesData['name'] ;
$emailadminTemplate['productname'] = $auction->getProductName();
$emailadminTemplate['totalbidder'] = $auction->getTotalBidder();
$emailadminTemplate['startdate']= $gdate ;$emailadminTemplate['starttime']=$ttime ;
$emailadminTemplate->send($salesData['email'],$salesData['name'],$emailadminTemplate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite the var "$emailadminTemplate". The model object becomes an array of parameters !

```
$emailadminTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('custom_email_template_to_admin_customproduct');
$emailadminTemplate->setSenderName($salesData['name']);
$emailadminTemplateParams = array();
$emailadminTemplateParams['name'] = $salesData['name'] ;
$emailadminTemplateParams['productname'] = $auction->getProductName();
$emailadminTemplateParams['totalbidder'] = $auction->getTotalBidder();
$emailadminTemplateParams['startdate'] = $gdate ;
$emailadminTemplateParams['starttime'] = $ttime ;
$emailadminTemplate->send($salesData['email'],$salesData['name'],$emailadminTemplateParams);
```